# How can I get running totals of integer values from a List()?

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

List has object which has properties as follows :

```
public class PropertyDetails
{

 public int Sequence { get; set; }

 public int Length { get; set; }

 public string Type { get; set; }

 public int Index { get; set; }

}
```

List will have sorted Sequence .

List has object values as follows:

Sequence= 1 Length=20 Type="" Index=0

Sequence= 2 Length=8 Type="" Index=0

Sequence= 3 Length=6 Type="" Index=0

Sequence= 4 Length=20 Type="" Index=0

Sequence= 5 Length=8 Type="" Index=0

I want Linq query which will give me result List as

Sequence= 1 Length=20Type="" Index=20

Sequence= 2 Length=8 Type="" Index=28

Sequence= 3 Length=6 Type="" Index=34

Sequence= 4 Length=20 Type="" Index=54

Sequence= 5 Length=8 Type="" Index=62

Where index is cumulative sum of Length considering sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I never though I'd say this, but I find Jon's solution to be overengineering. Rather, I find LINQ to be the wrong solution for this problem. You want to manipulate state, not a good fit for traditional LINQ-operators.

I'd just do this:

```
var sum = 0;
foreach (var p in list) {
  sum += p.Length;
  p.Index = sum;
}
```

LINQ is a hammer. Make sure you use the right tool for the problem, instead of just asking for hammering-advice.

Comment: You're *assuming* the OP wants to manipulate state. If that's the case, then this is the right approach. If it's *not* the case, then this isn't appropriate at all. You're right in saying that LINQ simply isn't suited for situations where you want to mutate existing objects. It's a great solution where you want a more functional approach though. It's unfortunate that we don't have enough information about what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There's no standard LINQ operator which does this - basically you want a running aggregation. You can fake it with a query with side-effects at the moment, but that's it.

Fortunately, it's easy to write your own query operator to do this. Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Scan<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TResult seed,
    Func<TResult, TSource, TResult> func)
{
    TResult current = seed;
    // TODO: Argument validation
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        current = func(current, item);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var query = list.Scan(new PropertyDetails(),
                      (current, item) => new PropertyDetails { 
                           Sequence = item.Sequence,
                           Length = item.Length,
                           Index = current.Index + item.Length
                      });
```

EDIT: I haven't checked the details, but I believe Reactive Extensions has a similar method in its System.Interactive assembly.

Comment: I don't really see the use for this. A database won't be able to process it effectively, right? And if it's for "LINQ for objects" then my question would just be "why"? Implementing a new extension method, creating new objects for each element in the list and on top of that still having to write more code than what would have to be done with a simple for-loop. LINQ can't be right for this.

Comment: @Jakob: There are plenty of situations where running aggregations are useful. I wanted one just the other day. I like to be able to express this aggregation in a declarative way, rather than writing a foreach loop. I also like to be able to use it as part of a larger query.

Comment: while I agree with your reasoning that it's useful to have a general solution that can be reused, I think that you have to be pragmatic first and foremost. In this case even the use of your solution (i.e. the second code block) is more code than the whole of Jakob's. His is also easier to read and understand. Your more general solution would, if used in more than one place generate more lines of code in total than copying and pasting his -- and we know that the number of bugs is proportional to the number of lines of code.

Comment: @Theo: It depends if the OP *actually* wants the original objects mutated. If he does, then Jakob's solution is more applicable. If he doesn't, then mine is more applicable. Using a functional approach like this can make the rest of the code much simpler to reason about, IMO.

Comment: @Theo I'd have to agree with @Jon on his last comment.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this (it's not very readable):

```
var newList = list.Select(x =>
                        new PropertyDetails()
                        {
                            Type = x.Type,
                            Length = x.Length,
                            Sequence = x.Sequence,
                            Index = list.Take(x.Sequence).Select(y => y.Length).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)
                        }
);
```

Comment: Awful, the time complexity of this is quadratic.